# Kubernetes TLS secret certificate expiration

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate

1. I use openssl to create a wildcard self-signed certificate. I set certificate validity duration to
   to ten years (I double-checked the validity duration by inspecting the certificate with openssl)
2. I create a Kubernetes secret with the private key and certificate prepared in step 1 with following `kubectl` command:
   `kubectl create secret tls my-secret -n test --key server.key --cert server.crt`
3. We use nginx ingress controller version 0.25.1 running on AWS EKS
4. I refer to this secret in the Kubernetes ingress of my service
5. When connecting to my service via browser and inspecting the certificate, I notice it is issued by
   "Kubernetes ingress Controller Fake certificate" and **expires in one year instead of ten years**

This certificate is used for internal traffic only, we expect the validity duration to be ten years.   Why is it changed to one year? What can be done to keep the validity duration in the original certificate?

`kubectl get secret dpaas-secret -n dpaas-prod -o yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: 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
  tls.key: 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
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-16T14:31:59Z"
  name: dpaas-secret
  namespace: dpaas-prod
  resourceVersion: "134564"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dpaas-prod/secrets/dpaas-secret
  uid: d1c692b6-2010-11ea-bce8-1247666f5179
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

`kubectl describe ingress ingress-test4 -n dpaas-prod`:

```
Name:             ingress-test4
Namespace:        dpaas-prod
Address:          ad6c6ea681f5d11ea91440a6af5c8987-559e0a22f4b3e398.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  dpaas-secret terminates
Rules:
  Host                                                 Path  Backends
  ----                                                 ----  --------
  test4.dps.mycompany.com
                                                       /   cpe-test4:80 (10.0.13.222:8080,10.0.38.178:8080)
Annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect:  false
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias:        test4.dps.us-east-1.mycompany.com
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect:        true
Events:                                            <none>
```

Comment: In general, "Kubernetes ingress Controller Fake certificate¨ indicates problems on the certificates itself or in your setup. May you update your question including the output of your secret (`kubectl get secrets <your-secret-name> -o yaml`) and your ingress (`kubectl get ingress <your-ingress-name> -o ymal`)? (You can hide sensitive information as you need.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, "Kubernetes ingress Controller Fake certificate" indicates problems on the certificates itself or in your setup. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1044), [here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/options/troubleshooting/#cert-cn-is-kubernetes-ingress-controller-fake-certificate), [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4674) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1984).

None of these posts will tell you how to solve your problem as the reason may be very wide and depends on your certificate and how it was generated.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4674#issuecomment-558504185) for example, it's reported that problem was not in the certificate itself but in his ingress:

> I just realized that I was missing the host in the rule per se (not
>   sure if this is required, but it fixed the issues and now the cert.
>   being used is the one I'm providing and not the Fake Kubernetes one).
>   Example of my ingress:

So, I as suggested in the comments, you reviewed the steps used to generate your certificate and discovered that adding the certificate common name to the list of SANs and regenerating the self-signed certificate fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simple command you can use to check cert expiration is:

```bash
kubectl get secret <secret-name> -o "jsonpath={.data['tls\.crt']}" | base64 -D | openssl x509 -enddate -noout
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Watney, your remark that "Kubernetes ingress Controller Fake certificate¨ indicate problems on the certificates itself lead me to further investigation. I discovered that adding the certificate common name to the list of SANs and regenerating the self-signed certificate fixes this problem :)

Comment: I my comment/answer helped you to get to the solution, please don't forget to upvote/accept my answer. Thanks.