# CertManager Letsencrypt CertificateRequest "failed to perform self check GET request"

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

*`Waiting for http-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request`, it's similar to this bug https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/656
but all solutions from GitHub ticket comments didn't help.*

I'm trying to set up `CertManager` on DigitalOcean as described in this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes
I didn't get any error but the request from `CertManager` is waiting in pending state more than 40 hours.

I have successfully configured Ingress with Nginx, then I created a namespace and created `CertManager` CRDs:

```sh
$ kubectl create namespace cert-manager
$ kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.12.0/cert-manager.yaml
```

I can see all `CertManager` pods as expected:

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace cert-manager
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager-5c47f46f57-gxhwv              1/1     Running   0          42h
cert-manager-cainjector-6659d6844d-xp75s   1/1     Running   0          42h
cert-manager-webhook-547567b88f-k4dv2      1/1     Running   0          42h
```

Then I created staging issuer:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: some@email.here
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

And updated Ingress configuration:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - echo.some.domain
      secretName: ingress-tls
  rules:
    - host: echo.some.domain
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: echo1
              servicePort: 80
```

But after that, `CertManager` didn't update certificate and waiting in `InProgress` state:

```sh
$ date
Wed 18 Dec 2019 01:58:08 PM MSK

$ kubectl describe cert

...
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2019-12-16T17:23:56Z
    Message:               Waiting for CertificateRequest "ingress-tls-1089568541" to complete
    Reason:                InProgress
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

Instead of using `Fake LE Intermediate X1` as a `CN` it returns `CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate,O=Acme Co`

```sh
$ kubectl describe CertificateRequest 
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2019-12-16T17:50:05Z
    Message:               Waiting on certificate issuance from order default/ingress-tls-1089568541-1576201144: "pending"
    Reason:                Pending
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

What can be the problem with `CertManager` and how to fix it?

---

Update:

Ingress logs contains these errors:

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx logs  nginx-ingress-controller-7754db565c-g557h 

I1218 17:24:30.331127       6 status.go:295] updating Ingress default/cm-acme-http-solver-4dkdn status from [] to [{xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx }]
I1218 17:24:30.333250       6 status.go:295] updating Ingress default/cm-acme-http-solver-9dpqc status from [] to [{xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx }]
I1218 17:24:30.341292       6 event.go:209] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"cm-acme-http-solver-4dkdn", UID:"2e523b74-8bbb-41c7-be8a-44d8db8abd6e", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"722472", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/cm-acme-http-solver-4dkdn
I1218 17:24:30.344340       6 event.go:209] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"cm-acme-http-solver-9dpqc", UID:"b574a3b6-6c5b-4266-a4e2-6ff2de2d78e0", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"722473", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/cm-acme-http-solver-9dpqc
W1218 17:24:30.442276       6 controller.go:1042] Error getting SSL certificate "default/ingress-tls": local SSL certificate default/ingress-tls was not found. Using default certificate
W1218 17:24:30.442950       6 controller.go:1042] Error getting SSL certificate "default/ingress-tls": local SSL certificate default/ingress-tls was not found. Using default certificate
W1218 17:24:33.775476       6 controller.go:1042] Error getting SSL certificate "default/ingress-tls": local SSL certificate default/ingress-tls was not found. Using default certificate
W1218 17:24:33.775956       6 controller.go:1042] Error getting SSL certificate "default/ingress-tls": local SSL certificate default/ingress-tls was not found. Using default certificate
```

---

Update2:

Secret for `ingress-tls` is available as expected:

```yaml
$ kubectl get secret ingress-tls -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: ""
  tls.crt: ""
  tls.key: <secret-key-data-base64-encoded>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/certificate-name: ingress-tls
    cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: ClusterIssuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-name: letsencrypt-staging
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-16T17:23:56Z"
  name: ingress-tls
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "328801"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/ingress-tls
  uid: 5d640b66-1572-44a1-94e4-6d85a73bf21c
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

---

Update3:

I've found that `cert-manager` pod is failing with log:

```
E1219 11:06:08.294011       1 sync.go:184] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="failed to perform self check GET request 'http://<some.domain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<some-path>': Get http://<some.domain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<some-path>: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80: connect: connection timed out" "dnsName"="<some.domain>" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="ingress-tls-1089568541-1576201144-1086699008" "resource_namespace"="default" "type"="http-01"
```

Challenge status:

```
$ kubectl describe challenge ingress-tls-1089568541-1576201144-471532423

Name:         ingress-tls-1089568541-1576201144-471532423
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
Kind:         Challenge
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-12-19T11:32:19Z
  Finalizers:
    finalizer.acme.cert-manager.io
  Generation:  1
  Owner References:
    API Version:           acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Order
    Name:                  ingress-tls-1089568541-1576201144
    UID:                   7d19d86f-0b56-4756-aa20-bb85caf80b9e
  Resource Version:        872062
  Self Link:               /apis/acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/default/challenges/ingress-tls-1089568541-1576201144-471532423
  UID:                     503a8b4e-dc60-4080-91d9-2847815af1cc
Spec:
  Authz URL:  https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/123456
  Dns Name:   <domain>
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:  cert-manager.io
    Kind:   ClusterIssuer
    Name:   letsencrypt-staging
  Key:      <key>
  Solver:
    http01:
      Ingress:
        Class:  nginx
  Token:        <token>
  Type:         http-01
  URL:          https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/12345/abc
  Wildcard:     false
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for http-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://<domain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<token>': Get http://<domain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<token>: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80: connect: connection timed out
  State:       pending
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From          Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----          -------
  Normal  Started    4m28s  cert-manager  Challenge scheduled for processing
  Normal  Presented  4m28s  cert-manager  Presented challenge using http-01 challenge mechanism
```

I tried to delete the challenge to re-trigger it, but it failed with same error after one-two minutes. I checked that I can access challenge URL from cluster nodes (using `kubectl run -it ...` and `wget http://<domain>/.well-known/acme-challenge/<token>` from inside new pod.

Comment: In general, "[Kubernetes ingress Controller Fake certificate](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/options/troubleshooting/#cert-cn-is-kubernetes-ingress-controller-fake-certificate)" indicates problems on the certificates itself or in your setup.

Comment: @mWatney thanks. I've found these logs in ingress-controller (see the update). Where I can find more verbose logs to find the main reason of this error?

Comment: Double check if this secret (ingress-tls under default namespace) exists and if it's correct (post `$ kubectl get secret ingress-tls -o yaml` here). Check your certificate, sometimes it can't load it because you have some error as you can check here is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356528) other case.

Comment: @mWatney looks like it's the same issue as in this [bug](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/656). I don't know why it failed to perform self checks. I fixed it after uninstalled `cert-manager` [fully](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/uninstall/kubernetes/) and installed it again.

Comment: According to me your Q&A is more on-topic on [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions). SO and SF are about software and system engineering respectively.

Answer (score 8):

This might be worthwhile to look at. I was facing similar issue with `Connection Timeout`

Change `LoadBalancer` in `ingress-nginx` service.

Add/Change `externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster`.

Reason being, pod with the certificate-issuer wound up on a different node than the load balancer did, so it couldn’t talk to itself through the ingress.

Below is complete block taken from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.26.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  #CHANGE/ADD THIS
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https

---
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the `cert-manager` wanted to request the challenge via an internal ip-address.

> failed to perform self check GET request 'http:///.well-known/acme-challenge/': Get http:///.well-known/acme-challenge/: dial tcp 10.67.0.8:80: connect: connection timed out

i.e. the DNS-resolution was broken. I fixed this by changing the deployment of `cert-manager` to accept only external DNS-servers like so

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
        - 8.8.8.8
      dnsPolicy: None
```

[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-dns-config) is how you do it. Also created an [Issue](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2970) so we can change that with the helm installation

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue it seems to be related with a bug in how Digital Ocean load balancer work. This thread [lets-encrypt-certificate-issuance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61087737/lets-encrypt-certificate-issuance) suggested adding the annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname: "kube.mydomain.com"` to the load balancer. In my case i did not had a yaml config file for the load balancer, I just copied the load balancer declaration from the [nginx-ingress install script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.43.0/deploy/static/provider/do/deploy.yaml)  and applied the new configuration to the kubernetes cluster. Below is the final config for the load balancer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: 'true'
    # See https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/controllers/services/examples/README.md#accessing-pods-over-a-managed-load-balancer-from-inside-the-cluster
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname: "kube.mydomain.com"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.19.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.43.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

Comment: This solved my problem, I just added the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname` annotation. I edited the resource with `kubectl edit service ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx`. Have in mind that you might have a different name and namespace.

Comment: +1 This also helped me. Fixed the internal endpoints of my bound services from an arbitrary IP address to the hostname specified. After apply the configuration change the Issuer was able to complete the challenge and the SSL was provisioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found the reason of this issue, so I'll post how I've solved it as answer.
Looks like it's the same issue as in this [bug](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/656). I fixed it by uninstalling the `cert-manager` [fully](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/uninstall/kubernetes/) and installing it again without changing any configurations ot settings.

Answer (score 0):

One of my CertManager pods was frozen so I deleted them all and they restarted. The certs renewed immediately.

`kubectl get pods -n cert-manager` (or whatever namespace your pods are in)

Then delete them all.

`kubectl delete pod -n cert-manager cert-manager-xxxx cert-manager-cainjector-xxxx cert-manager-webhook-xxxx`

Answer (score 0):

for Digital Ocean k8s deployments. 
generic `nginx-ingress` wont work. Install their nginx-ingress helm chart from marketplace. add `service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname: "kube.mydomain.com"` to annotations and you are good to go. 
It is unfortunate that these cloud providers all have their own customization required such basic apps and what works on one does not work on the other. The best, cloud agnostic way seems to be have our VMs/instances and deploy k8s there with k8s provisioners like rancher or RKE so that we dont keep customizaing our deployment across clouds.