# Cert-manager "remote error: tls: unrecognized name" errors

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I'm having an issue trying to create certs with cert-manager in a GKE cluster. This has to be something I am doing on my end as I have tried versions, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, and 1.6.2 with all getting the same error.

The error I am seeing is:

```
E0219 00:57:39.270717       1 sync.go:186] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="failed to perform self check GET request 'http://mysubdomain.mmydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/secretKey': Get \"https://mysubdomain.mmydomain.com:443/.well-known/acme-challenge/secretKey\": remote error: tls: unrecognized name" "dnsName"="mysubdomain.mmydomain.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="elasticsearch-tls-cert-somenumbers" "resource_namespace"="elastic-stack" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
```

This is the setup I went though to install:

Install CRDs
`kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.7.1/cert-manager.crds.yaml`

Helm install cert-manager

```
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.7.1
```

Confirmed install is good:

```
➜  ~ helm list -n cert-manager
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART               APP VERSION
cert-manager    cert-manager    1           2022-02-18 16:07:57.258172 -0800 PST    deployed    cert-manager-v1.6.2 v1.6.2
➜  ~
```

Applied the ClusterIssuer:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    email: "myemail@myemail.com"
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

Deployed my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ingress
  namespace: elastic-stack
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mysubdomain.mmydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kibana-kb-http
          servicePort: 5601
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - mysubdomain.mmydomain.com
      secretName: kibana-tls-cert
```

Then when I tail the cert-manager pods I see the `remote error: tls: unrecognized name" "dnsName` error.

A describe of the cert challenge says the same thing:

```
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://mysubdomain.mmydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/secretKey': Get "https://mysubdomain.mmydomain.com:443/.well-known/acme-challenge/secretKey": remote error: tls: unrecognized name
  State:       pending
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From          Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----          -------
  Normal  Started    8m45s  cert-manager  Challenge scheduled for processing
  Normal  Presented  8m45s  cert-manager  Presented challenge using HTTP-01 challenge mechanism
```

This works totally fine in another cluster, so I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Add the service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname annotation and edit the resource with kubectl edit service ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx. Have in mind that you might have a different name and namespace. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390660/certmanager-letsencrypt-certificaterequest-failed-to-perform-self-check-get-req)

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu I believe that annotation is only for AWS, but I could be wrong. The issue actually was that I used a different NGINX chart, and so the configs for ingress were different. When I switched the NGINX chat to the chart I used in the other cluster, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Just to elaborate more on this.

The error for me as well had to do with using the [nginx-stable](https://helm.nginx.com/stable) chart which [cert-manager](https://charts.jetstack.io) does not support instead of the [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx) chart.

So instead of this:

```
helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress \
  --namespace nginx-ingress \
  --create-namespace \
  --timeout 600s \
  --debug
  --set controller.publishService.enabled=true
```

Use this to install ingress-nginx:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx \
  --create-namespace \
  --timeout 600s \
  --debug \
  --set controller.publishService.enabled=true
```

And then install cert-manager:

```
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --atomic \
  --version v1.8.2 \
  --set installCRDs=true
```

Comment: I was facing this issue for last 2 days and was loosing my mind. This solved the issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The issue ended up being that I used a different nginx chart in my second cluster by mistake, so the configs for the ingress were different, and in turn not working. I switched the chart on my second cluster to the one that I used in my first cluster, and every thing worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Thanks for posting the resolution.

Comment: I ran into exactly the same problem with the same solution on AWS. It is a shame cert-manager does not emphasize that it only works well with the one on https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx and not with the other ones, including Nginx Inc's own Nginx Ingress Controller.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a very similar issue. The error read

```
remote error: tls: unrecognized name" resource_name=
```

My app and k8s cluster versions is as follows:

```
Nginx-ingress: 3.1.1
Cert-manager : v1.13.0
k8s Client Version: v1.24.1
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
k8s Server Version: v1.27.4
```

Adding the following annotations helped in solving the issue. The annotations are:

```
acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

The original issue ID: [6065](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/6065)